# fullcalendar not rendering correctly with meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

Another try to get this one sorted. I have created a repo at
https://github.com/pnunn/testFullCalendar
which has a running meteor app that shows the problem with meteor not rendering the calender correctly.

When first loaded, there are no visible events on the calendar. Navigate to the previous or next month and back again, and magically the events appear. If you click on an event and change one of the check boxes (the event color should change) the event is again not rendered either at all, or correctly until the page is manually refreshed.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this please? I've tried calling re-render, eventRender and every combination of functions from the calendar docs, but have yet to crack the magic one.

Thanks.

Peter.

Comment: Started working on that. Please take a look on https://github.com/parhelium/testFullCalendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per latest **Meteor 1.5.2** as on date and `fullcalendar:fullcalendar` below is the working code,

```
Template.packLayout.rendered = function(){
  calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) { // timezone added here
      // same code
    },
    editable:true,
    weekMode: 'liquid',
  }).data().fullCalendar;

  this.autorun(function(){ // Deps.autorun replaced here
    // same code
  })
};
```

> Note: `function( start, end, timezone, callback ) { }` is the latest `events` method as per [https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/][1]

Answer (score 5):

Fix for your issues are in https://github.com/parhelium/testFullCalendar.

First, reference to instance of Calendar is needed

```
calendar =  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({...}).data().fullCalendar;
```

Function using Requests.find() can be wrapped with Deps.autorun to rerun it every time Requests collection is updated:

```
    Template.packLayout.rendered = function(){

  calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick:function( date, allDay, jsEvent, view ) {
      Requests.insert({title:'Request',start:date,end:date,color:'red',className:'todo'});
      Session.set('lastMod',new Date());
    },
    eventClick:function(reqEvent,jsEvent,view){
      Session.set('editingReqEvent',reqEvent.id);
      Session.set('showEditEvent',true);
    },
    eventDrop:function(reqEvent){
      Requests.update(reqEvent.id, {$set: {start:reqEvent.start,end:reqEvent.end}});
      Session.set('lastMod',new Date());
    },
    events: function(start, end, callback) {
      var events = [];
      reqEvents = Requests.find({},{reactive:false});
      reqEvents.forEach(function(evt){
        event = {id:evt._id,title:evt.title,start:evt.start,end:evt.end,color:evt.color};
        events.push(event);
      })
      callback(events);
    },
    editable:true,
    weekMode: 'liquid',
  }).data().fullCalendar;

  Deps.autorun(function(){
    allReqsCursor = Requests.find().fetch();
    console.log("Autorun -> ", allReqsCursor.length)
    if(calendar)
        calendar.refetchEvents();
  })
};
```

Comment: That is fantastic Kuba Wyrobek... thank you so much. I was close, but would never have got there.

Comment: Ahh... there must be something still subtly wrong... I put the exact code from above (and I am running your test code happily) into my app and the calendar now blows up with Exception from Deps afterFlush function function: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Calendar.$.fullCalendar.events (http://localhost:3000/client/js/pack.js?abadf7a64b7fb1ca62b0ce2511ba8f416be34f1c:39:7)
    at _fetchEventSource (http://localhost:3000/packages/fullcalendar-2.js?36f6d4464ab673d5621be7a3c71bf8087cf49094:1383:12)
    at fetchEventSource ....

Comment: Full code is stored on github. Compare your version with this :https://github.com/parhelium/testFullCalendar.

Comment: That's what I've been doing Kuba (I think with a fine toothed comb). Must be something simple, I'll keep bashing away. The error doesn't really help me though.

Comment: Bugger it.. :)  I was missing one set of (). Amazing how long it can take to find!! Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks! :) It worked! Just needed to replace Deps.autorun with Tracker.autorun.